# C++ Node class, linked list, LIFO, FIFO

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I have to write a “programmer friendly” linked list. I have two classes, your main class and your node class. My node class will is my data structure and must contain the information listed below. All of the node information will be housed in the node class. My main class should only be a driver to call the node function.

Main class should contain:

- Code to call node class to append into your structure, LIFO
- Code to call node class to append into your structure, FIFO
- Code to call node class to display your structure

Your Node class should perform the following operations:

- Store: user ID, username, password, first name, last name, head, and next.
- AppendFIFO function:    Will take 1 integer and 4 strings
- AppendLIFO function:    Will take 1 integer and 4 strings
- Display function :  Will take no arguments

NOTES:

- I have 2 classes Node and your main class
- I have two Node objects in your main class, one for FIFO and one for LIFO
- My node class is where you will keep track of where the next node goes and where the head is, do not do this inside of your main class.
- Do not change the order in which you insert into your Nodes to get a LIFO structure and a FIFO structure.  (E.g. My first append function call for both FIFO and LIFO are given information for Zackary Moore)
- Do not change the order in which you display into your Nodes to get a LIFO structure and a FIFO structure. You should only have one display function.
- You must insert at least 10 users information inside of your main class.

My Node.cpp code looks like this: It is throwing this error:Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was nullptr.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "iomanip"


Node::Node()
{
}


Node::~Node()
{
}
void Node::AppendFIFO(int id, string userName, string password, string fName, string lName)
{

}
void Node::AppendLIFO(int id, string userName, string password, string fName, string lName)
{
    //cout << "Yo" << endl;
    Node *curNode;
    curNode = head;
    cout << "user name:" << userName.length();
    cout << "Password:" << password.length();
    cout << "f name:" << fName.length();
    cout << "l name:" << lName.length();
    while (curNode != nullptr)
    {

        curNode = curNode->next;
    }
}
void Node:: display()
{

}
```

My Node.h file looks like this

```
#pragma once
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "iomanip"

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
        Node();
        ~Node();
        void AppendFIFO(int, string, string, string, string);
        void AppendLIFO(int, string, string, string, string);
        void display();

    private:
        int ID;
        string userName;
        string password;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        Node *next;
        Node *head;

};
```

My code for the main.cpp file looks like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "Node.h"
#include "iomanip"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Node *LIFO = nullptr;
    Node *FIFO = nullptr;

    //The 10 users information for LIFO
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(10, "postMalone", "Asdkc34D", "Austin", "Post");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(9, "h20", "akdjW78v", "Benny", "Washington");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(8, "testing", "aklc5kaS", "Timmy", "Trump");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(7, "Rob-by", "robby3939", "Robert", "Malone");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(6, "TracyLMoore", "Moore098", "Tracy", "Moore");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(5, "Billybill", "Bb234", "Bill", "Prescott");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(4, "beth-09", "09ASDN", "Beth", "Richards");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(3, "Gabe123", "123ilkkSW", "Gabriel", "Smith");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(2, "sthomas", "sthom56712", "Shannon", "Thomas");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(1, "bob", "LKJG840", "Bobby", "Steve");
    LIFO->AppendLIFO(0, "zmoore00", "00SDJ", "Zackary", "Moore");

    //The 10 users information for FIFO
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(10, "postMalone", "Asdkc34D", "Austin", "Post");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(9, "h20", "akdjW78v", "Benny", "Washington");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(8, "testing", "aklc5kaS", "Timmy", "Trump");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(7, "Rob-by", "robby3939", "Robert", "Malone");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(6, "TracyLMoore", "Moore098", "Tracy", "Moore");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(5, "Billybill", "Bb234", "Bill", "Prescott");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(4, "beth-09", "09ASDN", "Beth", "Richards");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(3, "Gabe123", "123ilkkSW", "Gabriel", "Smith");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(2, "sthomas", "sthom56712", "Shannon", "Thomas");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(1, "bob", "LKJG840", "Bobby", "Steve");
    FIFO->AppendFIFO(0, "zmoore00", "00SDJ", "Zackary", "Moore");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the error. I also cannot figure out how to determine the length of the longest string in the group of strings and then store it to be able to use for setw for a proper display.Help Please.

Comment: I'm having a hard job understanding the task given, the names of the methods are confusing. But bruno is right, however these methods are supposed to work, you must at some point create some nodes. You aren't doing that at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is throwing this error:Exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr.

Your programs begin by doing

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     Node *LIFO = nullptr;
>     ...
>     LIFO->AppendLIFO(10, "postMalone", "Asdkc34D", "Austin", "Post");
> ```

and in *Node::AppendLIFO* you do

> ```
> curNode = head;
> ```

so you try to access to *head* while *this* is *nullptr*, then later you use the undefined result to do

> ```
> curNode = curNode->next;
> ```

---

Currently your program never create an instance of *Node*, it cannot works like that

Comment: So what would be the best way to fix it then?

Comment: @kenz but are you written the classes and method profiles by yourself or they come with the exercise ? I do not understand "main class"

Comment: @kenz perhaps you just have to create a first instance to be able to call the AppendXXX on it to add the next instances ? The first instance use _Store_ to update its attributes after a new just creating it (even the best way is to set the attributes is in a dedicated constructor of course)

Comment: The main class is the main.cpp

Comment: a file/function is not a class ;-) I Encourage you to edit your question clarify in it what is from you and what is coming from the problem you have to solve, because there are stange/inconsistent things in it. (and for me it is 1am so time to sleep ^^)